# new bounds for transformed random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Y \sim U\left ( 0,1 \right)$, I have already determined the new pdf for the transformation $Z=Y^2$. I used the cdf technique for this. So the new pdf for $Z=Y^2$ is $f_Z(z) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}$. How will I determine the new support for this pdf?

In general, what if $Y \sim U(a,b)$. How will the bounds of the transformation $Z=Y^2$ be determined?

Your insights will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < Y < 1$, then $0^2 < Y^2 < 1^2$, so it follows that $0 < Z < 1$.

More generally, if $a < Y < b$, then we must address three cases:  $$\begin{align} 0 \le a < b, \\ a < 0 < b, \\ a < b \le 0. \end{align}$$  In the first case, it should be clear that $$a^2 < Z < b^2.$$  In the second, because $0 \in (a,b)$, we must have $$0 \le Z < \max(a^2,b^2).$$  In the final case, we have $$b^2 < Z < a^2,$$ noting that the interval is **reversed**.